# Spring Web App - Simple JDBC Template Advice?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, web-applications

Quick question based on a spring web app i am creating.

How do you go about setting up the context of the application so that you do not need to set the datasource parameters for simpleJDBC all the time and can call getSimpleJDBCTemplate().queryfor.... and it be set up with the datasource.

This is how i currently have it and it seems to go against inversion of control that spring is meant to provide as this is in every dao!

```
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:ApplicationContext.xml");
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ac.getBean("dataSource");
    SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

ApplicationContext

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
<property name="location" value="classpath:properties.properties"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    </bean>

 <bean name="SimpleJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="dataSource"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>


      <context:annotation-config/>
   </beans>
```

Latest Stack Trace from Tomcat log

```
13-Jan-2011 20:15:18 com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  ptc.jersey.spring
13-Jan-2011 20:15:18 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class ptc.jersey.spring.resources.LoginResource
13-Jan-2011 20:15:18 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
13-Jan-2011 20:15:19 com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet getContext
INFO: Using default applicationContext
13-Jan-2011 20:15:19 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.4 09/11/2010 10:30 PM'
13-Jan-2011 20:15:21 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ptc.jersey.spring.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl.getUser(UserDaoImpl.java:43)
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>ptc.jersey.spring</param-value>
</init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Any help would be great 
Thanks 
Chris

Comment: Could you please also post you web.xml?

Comment: any progress on the issue? Unfortunately I ran out of ideas. For some reasons the context is probably not picked up, but the config looks ok.

Comment: @Timo No luck no yeah for some reason the application isnt being loaded by the container , I thought maybe some sort of servlet might be needed but I dont know enough about this . For now i just hardcode the context into an abstract class resource manager that allows DAOs to access a set up JdbcTemplate

Comment: The listener inspects the 'contextConfigLocation' parameter. If the parameter does not exist, the listener will use /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml as a default. When it does exist, it will separate the String using predefined delimiters (comma, semi-colon and whitespace) and use the values as locations where application contexts will be searched for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you declare the SimpleJdbcTemplate instance as well in the application context file?

For example with these bean declarations

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="dburl"/>
    <property name="username" value="dbusername"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean name="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="dataSource"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And in your web.xml to load the application context

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Am i right in assuming i would then be able to autowire the template to my DAO?

Comment: Yes, you will then be able to autowire it.

Comment: When I autowire it the template throws a null pointer exception? Any ideas why this would be it works fine locally its only on the tomcat server im running the app on that this exception is thrown.

Comment: Which class throws the Exception and when? The template when the template constructor is called? Maybe the autowiring fails at some point.

Comment: The Dao class on this line   return  simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, mapper, user);

Comment: I added an XML snippet for the web.xml configuration to load the context properly.

Comment: Still not working im adding the latest stack trace i get hopefully that will help it still says its loading the default context?

Answer (score 2):

Declare the SimpleJdbcTemplate bean in the context:

```
<bean name="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and use it like this:

```
ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:ApplicationContext.xml");
SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate = (SimpleJdbcTemplate) ac.getBean("jdbcTemplate");
```

or in a DAO:

```
@Autowired
private SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;
```

It is thread-safe, and therefore reusable.

Comment: for this application i will have many DAO's so havving these lines of code in each DAO isnt going to be great , would this work having a mian class that has a getter and setter that could provide the dao's with the JDBCtemplate?

Comment: Put your DAOs in your context too, and have the JdbcTemplate dependency injected.

Comment: I have tried this it however doesnt work, it works locally but when ran on the server it throws a java null pointer exception on the simpleJdbcTemplate

Comment: Add <context:annotation-config/> to your context xml. (Don't forget to import the context namespace)

Comment: Not working still getting null pointer tho in the tomcat logs it does say the application is using the default applicationcontext and not mine so is this maybe why im getting this error il add my files into the question.

Comment: Add <context:component-scan basePackage="..."/> to your xml, annotate your dao class with @Repository and get it out of your context using ac.getBean("dao")

Answer (score 0):

What I'd recommend is that you declare your `DataSource` as bean and **also** the classes which need it and use dependency injection to introduce the `DataSource` to your class. As an example, your bean definition could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">    
  <bean id="dataSource" class="...">
    <!-- your dataSource config here -->
  </bean>    
  <bean id="yourClassThatNeedsDataSource" class="com.stackoverflow.q4684102.Example">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>    
</beans>
```

and the accompanying class

```
package com.stackoverflow.q4684102;
import javax.jdbc.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.*;

public class Example implements YourDaoInterface {    
    private SimpleJdbcOperations jdbc;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
        jdbc = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(ds);
    }    
    // your DAO methods here
}
```

**Why do it this way instead of creating a bean out of the SimpleJdbcTemplate itself?**

No difference, really - some people like it the other way, some others like it this way - you wan't have a huge XML with loads of bean definitions for intermediate objects if you do it this way, that's for sure. That, of course, is up to you to decide on how you want to design your software.

Answer (score 0):

If you create SimpleJdbcTemplate inside setDataSource then you are creating a template per Dao instance.
If you configure as a bean and inject into the Dao, then you can resuse the same template across the Daos - which is recommended, because its threadsafe.